# Receiving indexError in Jupyter Notebook when passing data to another function

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am creating a product recommender and am having some difficulty with getting data into the comparison module. Here is a snippet of my data:

[Snippet of spreadsheet data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WD7T4.png)

and the code:

```
from scipy import spatial
def Similarity(Item1, Item2):
    a = products.iloc[Item1]
    b = products.iloc[Item2]
    
    keywordsA = a['keywords_bin']
    keywordsB = b['keywords_bin']
    
    kywdDistance = spatial.distance.cosine(keywordsA, keywordsB)

    return kywdDistance

def get_recommendations(name):
    
    new_product = products[products['Item'].str.contains(name)].iloc[0].to_frame().T
    print('Selected Item: ',new_product.PN.values[0],' - ',new_product.Item.values[0],' - ',
        new_product.Description.values[0],' - ',new_product.Keywords.values[0],' - ',
          new_product.Price.values[0])
    def getNeighbors(baseItem, K):
        distances = []
    
        for index, row in products.iterrows():
            if row['PN'] != baseItem['PN'].values[0]:
                dist = Similarity(baseItem['PN'].values[0], row['PN'])
                distances.append((row['PN'], dist))
    
        distances.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1))
        neighbors = []
    
        for x in range(K):
            neighbors.append(distances[x])
        return neighbors
    
    K = 10
    neighbors = getNeighbors(new_product, K)
    print('\nRecommended Products: \n')
    for neighbor in neighbors:
        print( products.iloc[neighbor[0]][0]+" | Keywords: "+
              str(products.iloc[neighbor[0]][1]).strip('[]').replace(' ',''))
    
    print('\n')
```

I have a drop down list that allows the user to choose an item and the functions are supposed to get items to recommend based on keyword similarity. Instead, I get the following error:

```
   Cell In[237], line 7
         1 button = widgets.Button(
         2     description='Get Recommendations',
         3     disabled=False,
         4     button_style='', # 'success', 'info', 'warning', 'danger' or ''
         5     tooltip='Get Recommendations')
         6 display(button)
   ----> 7 button.on_click(get_recommendations(name))

   Cell In[235], line 23, in get_recommendations(name)
        20     return neighbors
        22 K = 10
   ---> 23 neighbors = getNeighbors(new_product, K)
        24 print('\nRecommended Products: \n')
        25 for neighbor in neighbors:

   Cell In[235], line 12, in get_recommendations.<locals>.getNeighbors(baseItem, K)
        10     print(row.PN, ' ', baseItem.PN)
        11     if row['PN'] != baseItem['PN'].values[0]:
   ---> 12         dist = Similarity(baseItem['PN'].values[0], row['PN'])
        13         distances.append((row['PN'], dist))
        15 distances.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1))

   Cell In[26], line 4, in Similarity(Item1, Item2)
         2 def Similarity(Item1, Item2):
         3     a = products.iloc[Item1]
   ----> 4     b = products.iloc[Item2]
         6     keywordsA = a['keywords_bin']
         7     keywordsB = b['keywords_bin']

   File c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:1103, in _           LocationIndexer.__getitem__(self, key)
      1100 axis = self.axis or 0
      1102 maybe_callable = com.apply_if_callable(key, self.obj)
   -> 1103 return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)

   File c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:1656, in _ iLocIndexer._getitem_axis(self, key, axis)
      1653     raise TypeError("Cannot index by location index with a non-integer key")
      1655 # validate the location
   -> 1656 self._validate_integer(key, axis)
      1658 return self.obj._ixs(key, axis=axis)

   File c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:1589, in _iLocIndexer._validate_integer(self, key, axis)
      1587 len_axis = len(self.obj._get_axis(axis))
      1588 if key >= len_axis or key < -len_axis:
   -> 1589     raise IndexError("single positional indexer is out-of-bounds")

   IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue:

```py
for index, row in products.iterrows():
    if row['PN'] != baseItem['PN'].values[0]:
        locnbr = row.pn - 1                                 # added this line
        dist = Similarity(baseItem['PN'].values[0], locnbr) # changed this line 
        distances.append((row['PN'], dist))
```